# params.permit undefined method `=~' for Active::Record after ruby3.2.1 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alpine-linux

recently I updated from `ruby3.1.2-alpine3.15` -> `ruby3.2.1-alpine3.17`, the only gem update I did was `mysql2`, from `0.5.3` to `0.5.5` to support openssql3. And folow [Ruby3.2.0 Breaking Changes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/12/25/ruby-3-2-0-released/) and add the `--jit --yjit` flags. Almost all the app work just fine. But somehow a piece of code dont. Just a simple `params.permit`:

```
permitted_params = params.permit(:category_id, :private, tags: [])
```

which fail with a

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `=~' for #<HereGoes::MyModel>
```

And my `params` looks like this: (where "fields" y just extra data). Only weird thing i see is nested `ActionController::Parameters` but this same params is just parsed fine in older ruby version.

```
"#<ActionController::Parameters  {\"field_values\"=>[#<ActionController::Parameters 
{\"field_id\"=>4, \"value\"=>\"Test changed\", \"type\"=>\"string\"} permitted: false>], #
<HereGoes::MyModel id: nil, category_id: nil, uuid: \"87ebb507-e381-4d57-b66c-10e51f10c014\", 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: \"Alphazap5\", \"fields\"=> {\"Viva11\"=>nil,\"Y-solowarm4 
TextField\"=>nil,\"Y-solowarm4 StringField\"=>nil,\"Y-solowarm4 LocationsField\"=>nil}}, 
backup_id: 0, options: {}, tag_list: nil>=>{\"id\"=>1}} permitted: false>"
```

If I back to `ruby3.1.2` it works again. Both params are the same in `ruby3.1.2` and `ruby3.2.1` at the moment of execute the `.permit` method.

I dont know what more could it be. I haven't found anything in the ruby ​​or rails issues related to my problem. So... if anyone have an idea, I'll be grateful.

- I tried to keep same gems between ruby versions
- I compare both params in both ruby versions being exact the same
- I saw for changes in ruby3.2.x may affect indirectly ActiveRecord
- I tried disabling --jit --yjit para

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object#=~` has been removed (aka `Kernel#=~`):
*https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.2.html#removals*

---

The issue is here:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L1069*

```rb
next unless key =~ /\(\d+[if]?\)\z/
```

You have `HereGoes::MyModel` as a key in `params`:

```rb
{ "field_values" => [...], #<HereGoes::MyModel...> => {"id"=>1} }
```

This never got permitted before, since `Object#=~` just returns `nil`, which was the reason for [removal](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15231):

```rb
# v3.1.2
>> ActionController::Parameters.new({field_values: [], Class.new => {id: 1}}).permit(:id, field_values: [])
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"field_values"=>[]} permitted: true>

# v3.2.1
>> ActionController::Parameters.new({field_values: [], Class.new => {id: 1}}).permit(:id, field_values: [])
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:1069:in `block in permitted_scalar_filter':
undefined method `=~' for #<Class:0x00007fd63c224380> (NoMethodError)
```

You must be doing something else somewhere else to make it work.

Your models shouldn't really be in `params`, you'd have to share some code if you need help with that.

Comment: You were absolutely right!, I found a `params[An instance of my model] = {id: 1, name: 'blabla'}` in the code (git blame before I enter this job) . Before ruby3.2 `=~` just returned `nil`, so the problem in .permit was just ignored. Thx for the insight!